# DB2 replace emoji in text string

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I trying to find a way to replace emojis within a text string, I want to be able to set a pattern of
(a-z) and (0-9). if the string has other characters that don't match that pattern, i want to replace them with a space. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`.  See documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061496.html).

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(<your column>,'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]',' ',1,0)
```

You'll have to play around with the Regex expression to make sure it's not removing things inadvertently (punctuation, accent marks, etc).  I usually use [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to test things first.  Here is a test of the above pattern: https://regex101.com/r/Ebwtqp/1

For specific Regex help [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) will be your best bet.

(Thanks to [Paul Vernon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/155056/paul-vernon) for pointing out `[^A-z0-9]` isn't quite the same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]`)

Comment: Unfortunately DB2 doesn't support regex_replace. that is a sql server function.

Comment: @Banshee174 did you have a chance to follow the link to the Db2 documentation in the answer?

Comment: DB2 has regexp_replace which will replace any character in your pattern with whatever you chose. I don't see it doing what regex_replace does.

Comment: @Banshee174 Sorry, the "P" got left off when I was typing.  It shouldn't take too much to connect the dots.

Comment: @bbaird no problem, it just seems that DB2 is lacking in the regular expressions arena.

Comment: I would have to add all 3000+ emoji to my pattern in order for regexp_replace to work. I'm looking for something like this.                                                                    
 DECLARE Test NVARCHAR(500);
SET Test = N'this$is%a<>TEST,;to}⌡↕strip╞╟╚══¶out_ç_ƒ▀ special-ĳ-೫-chars-舛-დ-א-B';
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(Test, N'[\W\p{Pc}-[,]]', N' ', -1, 1, NULL);

Comment: That will replace any non-word within the string that is passed to it.

Comment: I think I understand what the documentation is saying. you give it a pattern to search for and it will replace any hits with whatever you need....or am I not understanding it correctly? In Sql Server the \W flag will replace any non-word characters that it find with a space..I don't see any flag doing that in regexp_replace. If I'm missing that part please correct me...thanks for your help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Banshee174 In regular expressions, `[A-z0-9]` means match letters/numbers.  `[^A-z0-9]` means match anything that *isn't* a letter/number. Again, trying the code and reviewing the example would be the first step.

Comment: @bbaird thanks! ^ is the part that I missed. let me try it. Thanks again.  :)

Comment: Note that `A-z` will match all characters between those two code points, so will also include `[\]^_`  and back-tick.  Therefor using `[a-zA-Z0-9]` would match the OP requirement more accurately.    Out of interest using `\w` to match a word character, will match this set: `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\u200c\u200d]`  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061533.html